# Why should we apply `flannel" after installing Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, repository, installation

In most of the Kubernetes installation instructions on Linux machines, there is such a commands:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
```

What is the above command and what does it do? Why there is no official repository for that?

Also like to know about the below command:

```
kubectl taint nodes --all=true node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

What happens if we run this commands after installation and what if we don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flannel is [Container Network Interface](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) (CNI)

Basically, CNI will help your pod or container in your cluster can communicate each other. You can read more at the link above.

About kubectl taint command. This command mean remove all taint node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule from all nodes in your cluster. This taint is always added to Master node to disallow schedule the application pod on Master node. In short, you can schedule your pods on Master node when you run this command. You can refer to this link: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/#concepts